# Undefined columns error when referencing element of data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to plot many graphs, and I am having an error referencing elements of a data.frame.

Rather than manually change the variable names I would like to loop through and reference the specific variable names.

When I do this I get the "undefined columns selected" error.

When I run this code, I get the correct plot:

```
xy <- lm(Unfairness_Scale ~ OS_ImpCoreV_A * ImpCoreV_A, data = 
branch_annual)
with(branch_annual, interact_plot(xy, pred = OS_ImpCoreV_A, modx = 
ImpCoreV_A))
```

When I run this code, I get the "undefined columns selected" error:

```
xy <- lm(branch_annual$Unfairness_Scale ~ branch_annual$OS_ImpCoreV_A * 
branch_annual$ImpCoreV_A, data = branch_annual)
with(branch_annual, interact_plot(xy, pred = branch_annual$OS_ImpCoreV_A, 
modx = branch_annual$ImpCoreV_A))
```

I have tried several different methods to reference the elements of the data frame but I keep getting the same error. What am I not understanding correctly?

Thanks,

Sebastian

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), it is a little hard to see what your question is/what you want. Which line gives the error? the `lm` or the `interact_plot`? Where did `interact_plot` come from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `as.formula` with character as input from your loop and construct the formula inside lm function.

```
xy <- lm(as.formula(paste('Unfairness_Scale', '~', 'OS_ImpCoreV_A', '* 
', 'ImpCoreV_A')), data = branch_annual)
with(branch_annual, interact_plot(xy, pred = 'OS_ImpCoreV_A', 
modx = 'ImpCoreV_A'))
```